# Mysql Why when I use group by Id the sum function doesn't calculate the summation of a column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have employees in our company, the employees borrow some money from their salaries & this borrowed money is to be know for us. also we need to know the remaining money from the salary in each transaction,and   the sum of borrowed money.

I created table employees which includes Salary column

as

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
 `Employee_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Employee_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Salary` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Employee_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2
```

And salary_transaction  table to save each borrowed money in money_amount column

```
CREATE TABLE salary_transaction (
 Salary_Transaction_Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Employee_Id int(11) NOT NULL,
 money_amount decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Salary_Transaction_Id)
 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3
```

This is my query and the problem it doesn't calculate the cumulative  sum of money_amount borrowed by specific employee.

```
SELECT t.Salary_Transaction_Id,
t.Employee_Id,t.money_amount,
sum(t.money_amount) as Total_borrowed,
e.salary-sum(t.money_amount) as remaining from salary_transaction t
JOIN
(SELECT salary,Employee_Id,Employee_Name from employees ) e 
ON
t.Employee_Id = e.Employee_Id GROUP by t.salary_transaction_id
```

[image]

**Edit**

**I provided my questions with scripts**

[All scripts here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=922cf392f158d4ae8ea9850e32634527)

**Edit 2**

Expected total_borrowed values

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.salary_transaction_id, 
       t.employee_id, 
       t.money_amount, 
       sum(t.money_amount) over (partition by employee_id order by t.salary_transaction_id) as total_borrowed, 
       e.salary - sum(t.money_amount) over (partition by e.employee_id order by t.salary_transaction_id) remaining
from employees e
inner join salary_transaction t on t.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by t.employee_id, t.salary_transaction_id, t.money_amount
```

You can use the OVER () function.

```
salary_transaction_id | employee_id | money_amount | total_borrowed | remaining
         1            |       1     |     3000     |       3000     |    4000
         2            |       1     |     1000     |       4000     |    3000
         3            |       1     |      500     |       4500     |    2500
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to substract the total amount borrowed by each employee from their salary. I would recommend a `left join` with pre-aggregation:

```
select e.*,
    coalesce(st.total_borrowed, 0) as total_borrowed,
    e.salary - coalesce(st.total_borrowed, 0) as remaining
from employee e
left join (
    select employee_id, sum(money_amount) as total_borrowed
    from salary_transaction
    group by employee_id
) st on st.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

You could also use a correlated subquery. In very recent versions of MySQL, lateral joins come handy:

```
select e.*, st.total_borrowed, e.salary - st.total_borrowed as remaining
from employee e
cross join lateral (
    select coalesce(sum(money_amount), 0) as total_borrowed
    from salary_transaction st
    where st.employee_id = e.employee_id
) st
```

---

**Edit**: both queries give you one row per employee. If you actually want one row per transaction, with a running sum of borrowed money and remaining salary, then it is different.

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select e.*,
    st.salary_transaction_id, st.money_amount,
    coalesce(sum(st.money_amount) over(partition by employee_id order by st.salary_transaction_id), 0) as total_borrowed,
    e.salary - coalesce(sum(st.money_amount) over(partition by employee_id order by st.salary_transaction_id), 0) as remaining
from employee e
left join salary_transaction st using(employee_id)
```

In earlier versions, an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, salary - total_borrowed
from (
    select e.*,
        st.salary_transaction_id, st.money_amount,
        (
            select coalesce(sum(st.money_amount), 0) 
            from salary_transaction st1
            where st.employee_id = e.employee_id and st1.salary_transaction_id <= st.salary_transaction_id
        ) as total_borrowed
    from employee e
    left join salary_transaction using(employee_id)
) t
```

Comment: your first query doesn't show me all transactions

Comment: and the second query has error in  SQL syntax.

Comment: @Nefazodone: so you want one row per transaction rather than one row per employee? See my update. Note that the solution depends on your MySQL version (that was clearly mentionned already for the second query), so make sure to use the solution that is appropriate for your database version.

Comment: I want a row for each transaction,My maiadb is no very recent

Comment: please look to my Edit 2